# Вывод данных из массива json

Tags: php, массивы, json

Есть json с данными, как в массиве `stats` выбрать нужную запись по name?  `json_decode($urljson)->playerstats->stats[0]` не подходит, так как данные могут отличаться местами

```
{
  "playerstats": {
    "steamID": "76561198161582003",
    "gameName": "",
    "stats": [{
        "name": "deaths",
        "value": 604
      },
      {
        "name": "kill",
        "value": 11800
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Что значит "нужную"?

Comment: к примеру, значение deaths

Comment: Так и надо уточнить это в вопросе, мы тут не умеем Видеть :)

Answer (score 1):

Без цикла не обойтись:

```
$str = <<<JSON
{
  "playerstats": {
    "steamID": "76561198161582003",
    "gameName": "",
    "stats": [{
        "name": "deaths",
        "value": 604
      },
      {
        "name": "kill",
        "value": 11800
      }
    ]
  }
}
JSON;
$json = json_decode($str);

$name = 'kill';
var_dump($json);

foreach($json->playerstats->stats as $stat){
  if($stat->name === $name){
    $stat->name = "Kill all humans!";
    break;
  }
}

var_dump($json);
```

https://repl.it/I22i/0

Comment: Спасибо большое